# Powershell import-csv conditional for column

Tags: powershell, csv, import, scripting

I'm trying to find the best way using Powershell to modify a row in CSV based on the following condition:

```
IF column TEST contains a WORD,WORD
THEN do the following:
 1) copy the entire row once but keep only the FIRST WORD in column TEST
 2) copy the entire row again but keep only the SECOND WORD in column TEST
 3) delete the original row that had WORD,WORD in column TEST
```

Example:

```
subject~school~TEST~code~year
math~PADF~true,false~0943~2016
```

I'd like:

```
subject~school~TEST~code~year
math~PADF~true~0943~2016
math~PADF~false~0943~2016
```

I'm no expert in Powershell, but I was playing around with using the import-csv, and then using a Get-Content Foreach-object, but it's not working. If someone knows of an easier way or the solution for the case above, that would be fantastic!

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

> knows of an easier way or the solution for the case above

With programming, there's generally no such thing as '*the*' solution. Write what you want to do (good steps 1,2,3 in your question) and then make up some code to do that:

```
Import-Csv D:\data.csv -Delimiter '~' | ForEach-Object {

    if ($_.TEST -match ',')                  # IF row.TEST contains a comma
    {
        $first, $second = $_.TEST.Split(',') # Get first and second words ready

        $_.TEST = $first                     # Output the record once with 
        $_                                   # first word

        $_.TEST = $second                    # and again with second word
        $_                                   #
    }
    else 
    {
        $_                                   # otherwise output it unchanged
    }
} | Export-CSV out.csv -Delimiter '~' -NoTypeInformation
```

Not entirely sure what you mean by delete, but you could run this and `Export-CSV out.csv -Delimiter '~' -NoTypeInformation` and it would output to a new file without the original WORD,WORD row.

Comment: This worked out great! I have a question, the Export-CSV out.csv -Delimiter '~' -NoTypeInformation didn't work for me. It would say the following: cmdlet Export-Csv at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
InputObject: , I would press any value and it would close and out.csv wouldn't be created. I wanted to use something like 'Set-Content $outputfile' after each scenario: first/second word/unchanged" but it's not working...  would that be easier or should we stick with the export-csv? I tried googling '-NoTypeInformation' for powershell and found nothing.

Comment: @Awsmike I have edited the code in my answer, I was thinking of one particular place to put it at the end (chained with the `|` pipeline for providing input to it) and I didn't make that clear. Export-CSV is better here than Set-Content because the things we're working with are `[PSCustomObject]`, not text, so they need some kind of converting to go in a file neatly - and Export-CSV does that bit.

Comment: Thank you! I saw someone else use the pipe for the same command afterwards and that worked. I appreciate the literature on the Export-CSV vs Set-Content.